# How to change the UIPopOver frame Background

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I want to change the border color of the popover in iOS6.

Can somebody tell me a technique that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

[WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) is a best option for you.
You can't do this with UIPopover, I don't know is it possible with ios 6 or not.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 6, you can customize the frame, arrow, etc.

Here's a [pointer to a blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/customizing-the-design-of-uipopovercontroller) that describes the technique.